# Django advanced nesting urls

Tags: django, url, overlap, nested

Welcome,

I've got a problem where I`m trying to make a deep nesting.
The thing is that I have Menu that has SUBMENU that can have multiple categories and those categories can have multiple services available and those services can have multiple products.
Writing urls for that specific thing was easy but when I'm trying to create a product that has no category and I want it to be displayed directly in SUBMENU  the problem is with writing url for that specific product that doesnt overlap with SUBMENU slug.

For example:

```
MENU > SUBMENU1 > CATEGORY 1 > AVAILABLE SERVICES > PRODUCT 1
MENU > SUBMENU2 
MENU > SUBMENU3 > PRODUCT 2
```

all of those names are slugged and my urls.py looks like this:

```
url(r'^uslugi/(?P<category_slug>\S+)/(?P<services_slug>\S+)/(?P<service>\S+)/$', views.show_service_details, name='show_service_details'),
url(r'^uslugi/(?P<category_slug>\S+)/(?P<services_slug>\S+)/$', views.show_services, name='show_services'),
url(r'^uslugi/(?P<category_slug>\S+)/$', views.show_categories, name='show_categories'),
url(r'^uslugi/(?P<product_slug>\S+)/$', views.show_product_without_cat, name='show_product_without_cat'),
```

The thing is that when I try to enter a product with no category (just placed in submenu), my urls are calling the `show_category` view. Changing sequence of those urls won't resolve my problem, because I won't be able to enter my `show_categories` because django will try to execute `show_product_without_cat`

I there a reasonable solution for this without redesigning all structure ?

Unfortunetely even saying to django in template to call specific VIEW doesn't help at all. It just goes through all urls and matches the first one

```
<a href="{% url 'show_product_without_cat' i.url  %}" >
                    <img src="/media/{{ i.image }}"> <br/>
                </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

URL dispatcher finds the first url that matches the request path and calls the found view. You have the same url regex for both `show_categories` and `show_product_without_cat` views so only the first occurrence of url will work.

The only solution is to create an intermediate view which will check the slug against `Category` or `Product` model and call the appropriate view.

```
def product_or_category(request, slug):
    if Product.objects.filter(slug=slug).exists():
        return show_product_without_cat(request, slug)
    return show_categories(request, slug)
```

And assign the url to this view:

```
url(r'^uslugi/(?P<slug>\S+)/$', views.product_or_category,
                                name='show_product_or_category'),
```

But note that with this solution you can't have a category and product with the same slug.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.
I managed to create one more simple nesting.
I'm displaying my product without category in the most basic link
`mysite.com/product`
I fought with this all previous night... all i needed was a sleep and fresh mind.
Also I tried your solution and It works just fine.
Have a nice day my friend.